# What is the smallest practical milliKelvin temperature sensor or technique?

Tags: experimental-physics, temperature, thermodynamics

I need to track the temperature of a mass of less than 1 gram, and the two constraints are accuracy and mass of the attached sensor/circuitry (it must be less than 1.5g). Ideally it should be a non contact solution, but if that turns out to be physically impossible I can tolerate some electronics in contact with the sample.

Comment: Do you mean milliKelvin accuracy, or down in to milliKelvin temperatures? And if the latter, how far down in to the milliKelvin (100mK is different from 1mK)? An optical technique using quantum dots for subkelvin tempatures is detailed in F. Seilmeier et al., 10.1103/PhysRevApplied.2.024002.

Comment: At what temperature? Does it have to be reproducible to one mK? A well aged resistive temperature sensor can provide the resolution easily and if you want to avoid contact, you can measure the temperature dependent extension of an object (at a hundred times the cost) remotely with an interferometer or something. If you can be right at the Curie temperature of a substance, then the Temperature can be measured magnetically.